# Guidelines for troubleshooting high interrupt rate

Tags: windows-xp, interrupts, system-calls

#### Sample readings:

- high or above normal interrupt rate (at idle), at approximately **1505/sec**
- Information obtained from [**Process Explorer**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and [**Kernrate**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=d6e95259-8d9d-4c22-89c4-fad382eddcd1)
- System calls approximately **6132/sec**
- Context switches approximately **1584/sec**

Possible faulty hardware or faulty device driver?

**Version:** Windows XP 5.1.2600

**Update:**

- Possibly, investigate which user-land processes (or threads) are responsible for certain system calls and why

Comment: I guess there's no point in me voting to move this

Comment: Sorry... I don't understand? What's wrong?

Comment: What makes you think it is a high rate?

Comment: What is a 'normal' rate? On idle times, that is wireless NIC disabled + bluetooth, rate as above. Is this typical? Guess I simply lack understanding... where/how can I dig deeper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a USB device connected (besides the 
keyboard/mouse)?

I experienced a similar problem to yours, but only if I 
connected a USB hard drive. The system would then go into a 
state that required a restart to get it out of. Even if the 
USB drive was unmounted the interrupt rate would still be 
high and the system was slow and not very responsive.

I tried all sorts of things, including removing the USB 
devices in the Device Manager and updating to the latest 
drivers. But nothing helped. In the end I bought a new 
computer as it was time to get a new one anyway. The USB 
drive was working perfectly on the new system so it was not the 
source of the problem.

I suspect it was either faulty hardware or a corrupted 
Windows installation.

In general I don't like to propose unspecific measures, but:

perhaps a first step could be to install Windows XP on a 
second empty hard disk and see if the problem goes away. If 
it does not then you can rule out a corrupted Windows 
installation or a corrupted file system (as it was installed 
on an empty harddisk).

Using this method you can return to your old Windows 
installation without the need to reinstall applications, 
etc. The second Windows installation can also be used as a 
backup installation if the first one fails - this can be 
very handy if you don't have time to fix the problem, but 
just want keep on working. (I also use it to switch back and 
forth between a 32 bit version and a 64 bit version of 
Windows - although a virtual machine would probably be more 
handy).

Comment: @Peter: None. Nothing besides what you mentioned. Wireless NIC + bluetooth is disabled (hard-switch).

Answer (score 2):

Check your drives/IDE channels in Device Manager Properties and verify that they aren't running in PIO mode. I've seen an issue like this before with a hard drive causing the system to have very slow performance. Windows XP (and higher) automatically "downshift" from DMA, or Direct Memory Access, to PIO, Programmed Input/Output, modes if problems are encountered with the data from the drive.

If this is the problem, could change the Advanced properties to use DMA mode if available or just delete the device and let Windows reinstall the driver.